# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements

Tags: python, oop, maps, geopandas

I can't add any more columns, even though I need the 'geometry' column to make the code run

```
 68 
 69         elif new_len != old_len:
```

---> 70             raise ValueError(
71                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
72                 f"values have {new_len} elements"

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements

7
8 df = pd.concat([floresta], axis=1)
----> 9 df.columns = ['floresta', 'geometry']
10
11 # Mapa cloroplético

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.